# converting DataHandler to byte[]

Tags: java, javax.activation, datahandler

I need a code snippt for converting `DataHandler` to `byte[]`.

This data handler contains `Image`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It can be done by using below code without much effort using apache IO Commons.

```
final InputStream in = dataHandler.getInputStream();
byte[] byteArray=org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
```

Answer (score 13):

You can do it like this:

```
public static byte[] toBytes(DataHandler handler) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    handler.writeTo(output);
    return output.toByteArray();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
private static final int INITIAL_SIZE = 1024 * 1024;
private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

public static byte[] toBytes(DataHandler dh) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(INITIAL_SIZE);
    InputStream in = dh.getInputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int bytesRead;
    while ( (bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) >= 0 ) {
        bos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    return bos.toByteArray();
}
```

Beware that ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray() creates a copy of the internal byte array.

Answer (score 2):

I use this code:

```
public static byte[] getContentAsByteArray(DataHandler handler) throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    handler.writeTo(bos);
    bos.flush();
    bos.close();
    bytes = bos.toByteArray();

    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: the close operation should be in a finally clause or you should use a Java 7 try catch.

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this what you are looking for?

```
public static byte[] getBytesFromDataHandler(final DataHandler data) throws IOException {
    final InputStream in = data.getInputStream();
    byte out[] = new byte[0];
    if(in != null) {
        out = new byte[in.available()];
        in.read(out);
    } 
    return out;
}
```

UPDATE:

Based on dkarp's comment this is incorrect. According to the docs for `InputStream`:

> Returns the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream without blocking by the next caller of a method for this input stream. The next caller might be the same thread or or another thread.

It looks like Costi has the correct answer here.

Comment: `InputStream.available()` is not appropriate for this purpose.  The `PipedInputStream` returned from the `DataHandler` returns the number of bytes available in its buffer before it blocks, not the total size.

Comment: Interesting. I've seen this code in many places when dealing with web services.